# longtable, description or glossary

Tags: longtable, description

I read that the use of tables from the typesetter’s perspective is unsightly and is only used more frequently because “Word” often does not allow any other option. In addition, there are technical difficulties. I have to write several documents in the same style, here the appropriate entry must always be entered for a label. With longtable, it can happen that the text in the cell is too long for one page. The only solution I have found is to manually split this cell. If I use description, it may be that the label text is longer than the text of the enumeration / description. What is the right way to create such a document? Here in StackExchange i read about the glossary-environment, which is compleatly unkown to me. Is it worth to learn?
Thanks for your help.

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{longtable, tabularx, tabulary, tabu}
\usepackage{multicol, multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{setspace}

\setlist[description]{style=multiline,leftmargin=!, labelindent=0pt}
\newcommand{\Linie}{\leavevmode \\ \rule{\linewidth}{1pt}}

    
\begin{document}
    \textbf{Longtable}
        \begin{longtable}{|>{\bfseries} p{0.3\textwidth} | p{0.7\textwidth} |}
            \hline
            [very long label, in some paper this is necessary and the text to this label is very long, but sometomes this long lable has a short text]&short text\\
            \hline
            short label&long text: \lipsum[1-5]\\
            \hline
        \end{longtable}
    \textbf{or Description}     
        \begin{description}[labelwidth=5cm  ]
            \item[short label] long text:\lipsum[1]
            \Linie
            \item [very long label, in some paper this is necessary and the text to this label is very long, but sometomes this long lable has a short text] very short text
            %\hline using hline is not the perfec solution?
            \item[hline or linie]I wonder why my line is so short and hline is longer? Which is better to use\
        \end{description}
\end{document}
```